# SQL Server 2008. Derived table calender ambiguous column name error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that looks up part information. How many parts there are, and the last time that part was ordered as well as some other things. I am unable to create a new table, or else I would just create a calender table and join them together.

What I want to do is fill in missing date information and leave the previous ending quantity the same until a new transaction was entered.

Here is a screenshot of the query results

[image: Query results]
and the code for the query itself.

```
Select t.txNumber, 
   t.item, 
   t.txCode, 
   t.txdate, 
   (t.onhandlocold + t.stockQty) as 'Ending Quantity',
   tmax.maxtnumber 'Latest Transaction Code',
   tmax.maxdate 'Latest Transaction Date', 
   tmin.mindate 'First Transaction Date', 
   DATEDIFF(dd,tmin.mindate,t.txdate) 'weight of transaction'

From tbliminvtxhistory t
Left outer join
     (Select t.item, max(t.txnumber) as maxtnumber, max(t.txdate) as maxdate
      From tbliminvtxHistory t
      Where t.txCode != 'PAWAY'
      Group By Item) tmax
  on t.item = tmax.item
Left Outer Join
     (Select t.item, min(t.txdate) as mindate
      From tbliminvtxHistory t
      WHere  t.txCode != 'PAWAY'
         and t.txdate > DateAdd(Year, -1, GetDate())
      Group By Item) tmin
  on t.item = tmin.item

where t.item = 'LR50M' 
and t.txCode != 'PAWAY'
and t.txdate > DateAdd(Year, -1, GetDate())+B10
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to a users input I am able to create a temporary calender that will solve my problem. Yet my lack of SQL knowledge stops me from using it correctly. On the last line of the code, specifically `on txdate = ''` it throws an error saying `ambiguous column name`. I tried using `t.txdate`, but this also throws an error saying `multi part identifier could not be bound`.

Since neither of those could be used I'm wondering if I didn't make mistake farther up in the code or what? If someone could find my mistake that would be awesome!

Here is the code:

```
declare @theDate  date
, @maxDate as date

set @theDate = '20150101';
set @maxDate = '20150105';
with dates AS
(select @theDate txdate
union all
Select dateadd(day, 1, txdate)
from dates
where dateadd(day, 1, txdate) < @maxDate
)
select txdate
from dates join tbliminvtxhistory on txdate = ''
```

Comment: You need a question. Apart from a few strange things (what is B10? Why do you select many rows per item?) there 's nothing obviously wrong with your query.

Comment: As seen in the screenshot under the txdate column there are gaps in dates. I want to fill in the missing dates without creating another table if possible because I am unable to create any tables. As far as what is in B10, it is where the SQL code lies. Our queries are ran and posted in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

based on your prose, you could create a derived calendar table.

```
declare @theDate as date
, @maxDate as date

set @theDate = '20150101';
set @maxDate = '20150105';


with dates AS
(select @theDate DateValue 
union all
select  dateadd(day, 1, DateValue)
from dates
where dateadd(day, 1, DateValue) < @maxDate
)
select DateValue, otherFields
from dates join someRealTable on datevalue = someDateField
```

Comment: I used that, however I am running into a problem adding the correct information into it. See edit for details.